# What does the 'a' means in Nand2Tetris C-instruction comp?

Tags: assembly, nand2tetris

When I was studying Nand2Tetris assembler part, I did not really understand about
the 'a'. How does it works?

In the unit, it doesn't use anyway why it exists.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation of the assembly language](https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/56440f_65a2d8eef0ed4e0ea2471030206269b5.pdf) slide 8 it is explained as a flag which is part of selecting which comparison operation to use. It selects whether to use A or M in the comparison.

See the lower left of this image.

[image]

Comment: So Coursera course I cannot find the slides that go along with the videos.  Where is the link that you used to find these slides for Chapter 6?